# [httpd]; make build/rules.mk:75: the rule for goal "all-recursive" failed

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, httpd

I try to install httpd from apche. Therefor I have to install pcre with the following command:

*in directory: pcre-8.39*

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pcre
make
make install
```

This worked quite nice.

After this, I was able to run the config programm form httpd without an error.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre/bin/pcre-config
```

So I tried the next step. The command `make`:

```
make
```

Here I got an error:

```
...
...
httpd-2.4.39/build/rules.mk:75: the rule for goal "all-recrusive" failed
make: *** [all-recrusive] Error 1
```

I use httpd version 2.4.39 and pcre version 8.39.

> versions
>
> httpd :   2.4.39
>
> pcre  :   8.39
>
> OS    :   Debian

My question is:

What I have to change to solve this problem?

Why does this error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem! (:

The expat.h library was not installed. So I downloaded the libraray from https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/releases and run the follwing commands in the expact folder.

*Directory: expact-2.2.7*

```
$ ./configure
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```